# Select an semi-redundant index to drop in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a 100GB data table with 264GB worth of indexes.
The table is basically a collection of session events with timestamps. The actual event data is quite short (a few couple of float measurements).

The table has three indexes worth rationalizing:

- `session_id` only
- `timestamp` only
- `session_id` and `timestamp`

A session has at most 10000 events with unique timestamp (a workday x 1 event per sec). Several sessions can have same timestamp but in practice only 500 events will share same timestamp (the physical process we measure is limited to that many sessions).

I guess the purpose of the first index is to find all events for a `session_id`. Likewise the second's is to find all events for a timestamp regardless of the `session_id`.

Now, I am really short on space. Can I get rid of the first two indexes? My assumption is that the query optimizer will just make a second pass after using the third index to filter out the unneeded rows, at a not so expensive cost.

Additionally, is there such a thing as a self-indexed/index embedded table? There is so little payload data that each index actually almost weighs as much as the data itself.

Comment: Unless the first index is a unique index you can safely drop it. Any query that uses that index, will happily use the third index as well.

Comment: valid for the second index (timestamp) too, I suppose ?

Comment: No, a WHERE condition using the timestamp can not be supported by the third index. You might want to read: https://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: IMO keep first and second, cause there will be surely some compaction worker which will keep records for last day which will look like `DELETE FROM sessions WHERE timestamp < TODAY`   (I mean without using `session_id`) , btw do vacuuming periodically: `VACUUM FULL VERBOSE sessions;`

Comment: No, we intend to not delete that data. And why would your example query suffer using the third index ?

Comment: please do `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE timestamp < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`  to see which index is used and other possible queries too.

Comment: Horse: my timestamp is an integer, probably a unix epoch

Comment: num8er: uses `timestamp_only`

Comment: num8er: I don't have enough space to `VACUUM FULL`. Not that there should be a lot to vacuum as I don't delete a lot, if ever

Comment: Take a look at the statistics tables here [Stat tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html) in particular `pg_stat_all_indexes` and `pg_statio_all_indexes` to get an idea of how heavily the particular indexes are being used.

Comment: `timestamp_only   10165836   |    5146849533 |    4634313726
session_id  493163705 |    6624207484 |    4852932839 
session_id_and_timestamp  119482297 | 109582895646 |  108087884803`